# QSettings doesn't work after building onefile using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller, qsettings

I am having an issue when building pyinstaller onefile version of my script my checkbox state doesn't get saved, but in the other hand when pyinstaller building normal exe with files the checkbox state is saved and works perfectly.

Note that I am using resources(package)>`__init__.py` to store my icons and config.ini and the icons works in both cases onefile or normal build.

Project files picture

[image]

`__init__.py contents`

```
from pathlib import Path

resources = Path(__file__).parent

config_ini = resources / "config.ini"
```

`My PyQt5 Gui.`

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings

import resources

import PyQt5.QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *



settings = QSettings(str(resources.config_ini), QSettings.IniFormat)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.main_ui()
        self.buttons()
        self.layout()
        self.show()
        settings.sync()


    def main_ui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Files Organizer")

    def buttons(self):
        self.checkbox_startup = QCheckBox("Run on start up")

        self.checkbox_startup.setChecked(False)
        self.checkbox_startup.setChecked(settings.value("startup_state", type=bool))

        self.checkbox_startup.toggled.connect(self.startup_settings)

    def layout(self):
        self.horizontalGroupBox_options = QGroupBox("Options", self)
        verticalbox_options = QVBoxLayout()
        verticalbox_options.addWidget(self.checkbox_startup)
        self.horizontalGroupBox_options.setLayout(verticalbox_options)
        self.horizontalGroupBox_options.resize(360, 80)
        self.horizontalGroupBox_options.move(20, 110)

    def startup_settings(self):
        startup_state = self.checkbox_startup.isChecked()
        settings.setValue("startup_state", startup_state)
        print("startup state is ", settings.value("startup_state", type=bool))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    screen = Window()
    screen.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: what is `resources`, provide a [mre], show the content of resources.py. What is your Python, PyQt5, Pyinstaller version?

Comment: Your code generates many errors

Comment: This is a sure code to show the code my whole GUI is too long. I am using  Pyinstaller 3.6,PyQt5 12.7.0

Comment: I have not asked you for the code of your project, I have asked you for an MRE, if your project is small then it can be an MRE but if your project is large as it seems your case then you must create a new project aimed at solving the problem in specific.

Comment: will make workable code few mints.

Comment: If you do not provide an MRE then I will vote to close your question.

Comment: PyQt5 12.7.0???The current version of PyQt5 is 5.14 so you point out it is impossible.

Comment: I added an MRE and details, this is my PyQt5 version sorry, PyQt version: 5.14.1

Comment: Okay, add the information of your environment in your question (pyqt5 version, OS, python version, etc.), also indicate clearly what is the command you use to convert to .exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered outside of stackoverflow at Python Discord by user Numerlor

> onefile works by extracting it's contents to a temp directory, that has its
>   path stored in `sys._MEIPASS`. So you setting the values in
>   `resources.config_ini` only changes the extracted file, which is removed
>   after you close the program
>
> qt has a bunch of paths under `QtCore.QStandardPaths.writableLocation`
>   that might be where you want to store config, like
>   `QtCore.QStandardPaths.writableLocation(QtCore.QStandardPaths.AppConfigLocation)`
>   which returns `.../appdata/local/{org}/{app}`

These lines are added at the begging of the GUI.

```
# This return .../appdata/local
local_path = QStandardPaths.writableLocation(QStandardPaths.AppConfigLocation) 
# Make directory for my program
os.makedirs(local_path + "\\" + "FilesOrganizer", exist_ok=True) 
# Making config.ini file.
config_path = local_path + "\\" + "FilesOrganizer" + "\\" + "config.ini" 
settings = QSettings(config_path, QSettings.IniFormat)
```